# Need better if condition between two time intervals in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to use the below if condition in SLQ to return a particular value every day between 07:25 Pm to 8:35 AM, but this condition is failing sometimes and not giving the expected result. on observing noticed a few cases when the server time is between 00:00:00 hrs 00:24:00 hrs. Can someone help with any alternative option? I am using this condition in Tabular Function

```
If (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),108)>'19:25:00') and (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),108)<'8:35:00')
Begin
Return @string

End
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is very product specific.)

Comment: Comparing time values as strings seems potentially problematic. `9:30:00` compares as greater than `20:00:00`, because of the first character. Generally, prefer *appropriate* data types.

Comment: "this condition is failing sometimes and not giving the expected result" - when, and with what wrong result? Anyway, you're treating timestamps as strings, which is very wrong, because you're going to get a literal character-by-character sort, not one that knows what times are earlier/later than which other times. So you should compare them as times.

Comment: In That case will the below option work

Declare @date time=getdate()

If (@date>'22:15:00' or @date<'09:00:00')
Begin
Return
End

Comment: Probably not because comparing a date/time value to a string. Also, the getDate() probably returns date component, not time. Any comparison of date/time values needs to deal with date component as well as time. For comparing strings, include placeholder zero: 09:30:00 will sort before 20:00:00.